# differential equation of a population growth and change - another question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations, exponential-function

I formulate a system of equations and initial conditions of the following data:
Each year the population1 grows by 4% and population2 by 2%.
Also each year 3% of population1 leaves it and go to population2
and 1% vice versa, leaves population2 and goes to population1.

The initial populations are: population1 = 20000000, population2 = 5000000.

I thought of the next formalism of this:
$$x(t+1)=1.04*x(t)-0.03*x(t)+0.01*y(t)$$
$$y(t+1)=1.02*y(t)-0.01*y(t)+0.03*x(t)$$

where $x(t)$ is the size of population1 and $y(t)$ is the size of population2.

then:

$$x'\left(t\right)=\frac{x\left(t+1\right)−x\left(t\right)}{\left(t+1−t\right)}=\left(1.04−0.03−1\right)x\left(t\right)+0.01y\left(t\right)$$

and similarly:

$$y'\left(t\right)=\frac{y\left(t+1\right)−y\left(t\right)}{\left(t+1−t\right)}=\left(1.02−0.01−1\right)y\left(t\right)+0.03x\left(t\right)$$

thus:

$$x'=.01x+.01y$$ and $$y'=.03x+.01y$$

where $x'$ and $y'$ are the yearly change in the population.

Now I want to calculate the whole growth temp, i.e the whole change of the population in the long run, i.e $$\lim _{t\to \infty }\left(z'\left(t\right)\right)$$
where lets define $z$ as the whole change as a function of t, the time.

I already found correctly x(t) and y(t):

$$x\left(t\right)=\left(10+\frac{5}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)e^{\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{100}t}+\left(10-\frac{5}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)e^{\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{100}t}$$

$$y\left(t\right)=\left(10\sqrt{3}+\frac{5}{2}\right)e^{\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{100}t}-\left(10\sqrt{3}-\frac{5}{2}\right)e^{\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{100}t}$$

both in millions (doesn't matter too much, but to be accurate).

Will it be correct to write:

$$z' = x'+y' = .04x+.02y$$
and then:
$$z'\left(t\right)=0.04\left[\left(10+\frac{5}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)e^{\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{100}t}+\left(10-\frac{5}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)e^{\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{100}t}\right]+0.02\left[\left(10\sqrt{3}+\frac{5}{2}\right)e^{\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{100}t}-\left(10\sqrt{3}-\frac{5}{2}\right)e^{\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{100}t}\right]$$

but in this case when $\lim _{t\to \infty }$ the whole expression goes in $\infty$ and i'm not sure this is correct.

So what is the correct approach to get the right total groth rate of the whole population ?
Thank you.

Edit:

Another idea is to define $z = x(t)+y(t)$
and then to derive z w.r.t t and calculate the limit in infinity.

Comment: Going to ∞ is correct; you have two populations that are exponentially growing forever, with some mixing. The wording of the question seems a bit imprecise; I couldn't tell whether the growth happens before or after the shift in population from group to group.

Comment: But did you account for the people leaving, not just arriving?  There should be some minus signs in those equations.

Comment: you are right about the wording, let's think about it as at the end of the year, i.e first the growth and then the shift. 
For the second note, the minus happens in the development of the system of equations. I've also fixed a small typo of '+'instead of '-' in the $y(t)$ equation. Now it is accurate.
Are you saying that the growth rate is going to infinity ? 
I agree that the amount of people goes to infinity, it is obvious, but the growth rate should be some constant I think.

Comment: I see the minus signs now.  But isn't your goal to find the limit of z' / z, not z'?

Comment: My colleague also said that about the $z'/z$, why is that ?
I.e, in my logic the z' is the growth rate, isn't it ?

Comment: If you have a long term .005 growth rate, for example, then when you have $z = 10^6$ your growth rate z' is 5000, and when you have $z = 10^9$ your growth rate is $5x10^6$. And .005 times infinity is infinity.

Comment: Ok, yeah, so dividing by z I get the rate in %, because it is the growth in people divided by the whole number of people in the appropriate $t$.